# How to overwrite django CACHE settings in tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, caching, testing, settings

I'm using `django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache` in my tests, however, there is one test which requires actual caching so I want to overwrite the CACHE setting for this one particular test. I want to test calling a [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) view within a url which make use of [cache_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf) url configuration.

To archive this in my test I use the `@override_settings` like this: `@override_settings(CACHES={'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}})`.
This works fine if I only run this test. But now some other tests are failing. In the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.modify_settings)

I found a warning which says:

> Altering the CACHES setting is possible, but a bit tricky if you are using internals that make using of caching, like django.contrib.sessions. For example, you will have to reinitialize the session backend in a test that uses cached sessions and overrides CACHES.

So I assume I have to reinitialize the middleware-stack or the urlconf somehow. But I'm not sure and get stuck at this point.

Comment: Are you decorating just the `TestCase` you need? Could you post the entire test file? and if possible to indicate which tests fail when you overwrite the setting

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I use `LocMemCache` for testing, and call `cache.clear()` before each unit test in the setUp method- which guarantees a clean working cache for each unit test.

Comment: @trinchet unfortunately I can't upload the whole test file. But [here](https://gist.github.com/t-io/35943b0b675d6761167a) is the critical part of the test class. Both tests succeed if called separate. When running the whole test suite overwriting the setting is ignored and no caching happens.

Comment: Try to decorate the class instead the method, and clear the cache in the setUp method as Derek suggested.